# JQuery not loading click on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

im using Bootstrap and im trying to do a left menu that load the link inside a right content

the function:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    alert("HI, working");
    $("#protocolar").on("click", function() {
        $("#conteudo").load("content.html");
    });
});
```

the `alert("HI, working");` is not called

the div that i want to load the page:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                <div class="well">
                  <div id="conteudo">
                  aqui vai o conteúdo

                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

code of the index.jsp

```
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">
                            </span>Atendimento</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><a id="protocolar" href="" >Protocolar</a>
                                    </td>
                           ... the rest of the code
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
            <div class="well">
              <div id="conteudo">
              aqui vai o conteúdo

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/teste.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/menuLoad.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `the hi is not called`

Comment: well as that is not inside any function it looks like you have a javascript error or not including the code.  Use firebug or inspect element to examine.  BTW, not sure why this is tagged as java.

Comment: sorry, because i use java as backend, but ok i know this is just html5/js problem, sorry =x

Comment: Try searching for "delegated event handlers" !

Comment: try looking at your console if you have error warning.